# Change NSOpenPanel button text

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am using NSOpenPanel to select the folder by the user where I can copy some files programatically.

```
NSOpenPanel *panelOpen = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
        [panelOpen setMessage:@"Please select a location to save file(s)."];
        [panelOpen setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
        [panelOpen setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
```

This opens the Open dialog with the button "Open". I want to change the button text to "Choose" or "Select" instead of "Open".

Is this possible?

Comment: The docs, my friend, read the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/setPrompt:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As clearly visible from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSavePanel) - note look into `NSSavePanel` which NSOpenPanel inherits from.

You can use `setPrompt:`for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just prompt rather than setPrompt, in latest Swift.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `setPrompt:` provided by `NSOpenPanel`'s superclass `NSSavePanel`.